# Why doesn't force:navigateToSObject support "Open Link In new Tab"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, navigation

I am trying to avoid hacking urls so I am using force:navigateToSObject. The only problem is what you cannot Cmd+click or Right click + "Open Link In new Tab" to navigate to the object in a new tab. This seems like something that should be already implemented. Anyone have a work around with force:navigateToSObject?

Comment: That's because it's not html but javascript so I don't know if it's possible to right click and open link in new tab. You can however use navigatetosobject so that it opens in a new tab, but if you want the user to be able to choose, then I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach will be to use Salesforce Lightning Console App.

Lightning console app has tabbed structure. They even have an API to open new tabs.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_opentab.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigateToURL event.
Maintain a base URL like `https://test-salesforceBaseURL.com/`
Append a relative URL by adding the ID of the record which you want to redirect

```
    var baseURL = 'https://test-salesforceBaseURL.com/';
    var recordId = /*recordID*/
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": baseURL+recordId 
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
```

Answer (score 0):

force:navigateToSObject is a lightning event. Lightning is a single web application. Lightning is not ready to open new tabs, because in the lightning's first load it load a lot of information.

You can use javascript to open it in a new tab, but i think that it is a wrong approach.

[There is the trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration) of lightning alternatives to javascript buttons